# so much not alike

Tags: negation, so

a. Those twins are so not alike.

b. Those twins are so much not alike.

c. He was so not in a hurry.

d. He was so much not in a hurry.

(Meaning of (c) and (d): He was not in a hurry at all.)

Are the above sentences grammatically correct and natural?

Many thanks

Comment: `b.` and `d.` would never be used.  `a.` and `c.` are slang only, a kind used by some young people.  They have a [valley girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_girl) flavor, as in "Like, oh my god, the twins are _so_ not alike."

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  This site is not intended to help people answer quiz or homework questions.  Please share what research you have already done, and what you found that confused you.  What do you think the answer might be?  (To improve your question, use the **[Edit]** button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

A & B, no. A native speaker is more likely (no pun intended) to say, "so different", or possibly "so unalike." Occasionally, one might hear "They're very much unalike."

C & D are also unlikely, though possibly acceptable. "He was lethargic." Or use "lackadaisical", "slow as a snail", "slow as molasses in winter", or [other synonym](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lethargic).

Answer (score 1):

None of them are grammatically correct! Or natural!

B and D are **certainly not**! A and C are **perhaps** allowable **if** you are under twenty and are speaking to a friend. (The word *'so'* has recently become fashionable and kids are using it far too much.) "So not" and "so much not" are simply never used in this context.

We would say (in the UK):

a) "Those twins are not alike." (Or, more often "Those two don't look like twins")

b) "Those twins are not at all alike." (Or maybe, "Those two really don't look like twins")

c) "He wasn't in a hurry."

d) "He certainly wasn't in a hurry." (Or maybe, "He really wasn't in a hurry.")